# Box with triangle tooltip issue(css,html)

Tags: html, css

```
<span className={style.tooltip}>
<text className={style.textHeaderTooltip}>Telegram token</text>
</span>

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 218px;
  height: 175px;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(19, 43, 95, 0.29);
  background-color: #575f7a;
  margin-left: 61rem;
  margin-top: 23rem;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  &::after {
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid #575f7a;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}
```

[image]

How to make triangle be a part of my tooltip, I can't understand what is the reason that this isn't the same block. What should I do to get a better variant of this tooltip version?

Comment: You want the triangle to be attached to the tooltip (the grayish blue box I'm guessing)?

Comment: I changed this margin-top: 100%; to 97 and get it attached, but is exist some method to make it as one block?

Comment: It caused by the border (`border-top: 8px solid transparent;`) i think the only way is adding a negative margin top.

Comment: You've got to place it manually by using ```margin``` There is no other way to make these 2 items one cohesive object